# No shipping method listed while editing order from admin in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, error, shipping-methods

From admin when I go to

> Orders -> click on any order -> when opened

it has **EDIT option, Add item, update items and Qty**

when u submit order than showing error **"shipping method must be specified"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before Submiting the order , click on one of the checkboxes in Shipping Method section like in this screenshot [image] .

Comment: There are no methods available.

Comment: Click first the Payment Method in able to Display the Shipping Methods

Comment: Currently showing in the shipping methods box  "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

Comment: Check the address / the products . Make sure you have a Zip code in address

Comment: Did you figure it out ?